# Matrix factorizations as a dg-category?

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, dg-categories, cohen-macaulay-rings

Matrix factorizations (in the graded case) give a triangulated category. I would imagine that there should be an underlying dg-category. Is there such a definition, and if so, where can I find it in the literature?

Comment: Have you looked into http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0135?

Comment: No, I haven't, will try to make sense of it. Is there a place there that I should be specifically focusing on?

Comment: I thought Preygel's thesis was another reference for this, but I guess it's more $\infty$ than dg.

Comment: Are you referring to http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.5834.pdf ?

Comment: @LevBorisov yes (or his actual thesis). I hope it's relevant...

Comment: @bananastack
I am looking for something really simple, maybe half a page or so. Perhaps this is just too much to hope for.

Comment: Maybse section 1 of http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_2011__61_7_2609_0.pdf is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Meow Yes, this looks like what I was asking about. Now, if I could only remember why ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Definition 2.7 of "A Category of Kernels for Equivariant Factorizations,
II: Further Implications" by Ballard-Favero-Katzarkov might be what you are looking for: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2656.pdf.

Their setup is quite general; to get graded matrix factorizations of a degree $d$ element $f$ of a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded commutative algebra $R$ over a field $k$ from their definition, take $\mathcal{A}$ to be $\operatorname{gr-mod}-R$, $\Phi$ to be grading shift $d$ times, and $w$ to be multiplication by $f$.